# pymqi on macos Library not loaded: @rpath/libmqic_r.dylib pymqe

Tags: python, intellij-idea, ibm-mq, macos-mojave, pymqi

I am running on macOs Mojave and developing a Python project with Intellij.

Running it produces this error:

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/guilhermemarcondes/IdeaProjects/ODOO_ENV2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymqi/pymqe.cpython-36m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libmqic_r.dylib
Referenced from: /Users/guilhermemarcondes/IdeaProjects/ODOO_ENV2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymqi/pymqe.cpython-36m-darwin.so
Reason: image not found
```

1. Installed XCODE
2. Created a ENV from scratch
3. Download and unzipped the toolkit from mac to OPT/MQM
4. Performed the Export for MQ installation and DYL .
5. Install the pymqi

But got the same error.

Please help.

Comment: Clarified wording, formatted code and bullets

Comment: Try running your code from the system terminal, outside of IDE (using the same python interpreter and environment). Determining if IDE is related might help with further troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for the tip... I did that and it worked as expected when I run via terminal into the  virtual environment . However  when I run the same simple code via IDE pointing to the same virtual env  I got the error, so pretty sure is something related to the IDE.. I am using INTELLIJ so not sure  what may be the issue